# $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix and $A^2 = A$, then what are the possible values of $|A|$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

If $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix and $A^2$ = A, then what are the possible values of |A|?

Comment: So I guess $|A|$ stands for $\det A$... and not $\sqrt{A^*A}$ as usual. By the way, you can go further: $\det A=0$, unless $A=I$.

Answer (score 4):

$|A^2|=|A|^2$, so you will get $|A|^2=|A|$. That's why either $|A|=0$ or $|A|=1$.

Comment: Well, this is certainly a better answer than mine.

Answer (score 1):

$A$ satisfies the polynomial $x(x-1) = 0$, so the only eigenvalues can be $1$ and $0$.